# Power Query and national formats

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

How to define national formats during PQ load? I have csv files being imported into Excel 365 and not all of them follow common US format. I need to define for file (or column) if it uses comma or period as a decimal sign, or if the date format in the file is DD-MM-YY or YY-MM-DD and such. Would be lovely to say 'this is French file, this is US file, this is German...' and it would sort it out, but manual settings per column would be also perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on `Transform`
Then, within the PQE, right click on the relevant column and choose:

`Change Type => from locale`

That will bring up this dialog:

[image]

and you'll be able to select the appropriate type and locale.

Comment: Sneaky little option, got it. Thanks.